# how to pass json file name to jq?

Tags: command-line-arguments, jq

currently I call

```
cat my_file.json | jq
```

to pretty print json data. I am a bit surprised that I can't do

I would like to avoid the extra `cat`; i.e.,

```
jq my_file.json
```

Can I specify a file name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the jq program to run:

```
jq . my_file.json
```

### jq -h

The usage line produced by jq -h:

```
Usage:  jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]
```

Note that the summary produced by invoking jq with the -h option does not (currently) provide a complete listing of the options.  For the supported options, see the jq manual: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

Two undocumented options of note are:

```
--debug-dump-disasm
--debug-trace
```

### `jq .`

Under certain circumstances, `jq .` can be abbreviated to `jq` but it's always safe to use the full form; a good rule of thumb is: if in doubt, do so.